# Python file existence checks loop crashes - unless I add a print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm porting a program from Python2 (don't know the exact version used) to Python3.3 and updating a few things, but this loop that checks the existence of a set of recently accessed file paths against the actual files crashes.

```
for index in range(story.recentFiles.GetCount()):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(story.recentFiles.GetHistoryFile(index)): pass
    except IOError:
        self.RemoveRecentFile(story, index)
        break
```

Accessing a single file works fine, so it's something to do with the loop. If I step through the loop with a debugger, the code works fine, but if I just run the application, it crashes on a "python.exe has stopped responding" error.

The weirdest part, though, has got to be that when I add a print statement before the `os.path.exists`, it works on a regular runthrough:

```
for index in range(story.recentFiles.GetCount()):
    try:
        print('test') # Why does printing this make it not crash??
        if not os.path.exists(story.recentFiles.GetHistoryFile(index)): pass
    except IOError:
        self.RemoveRecentFile(story, index)
        break
```

What is up with that? I'm assuming it has some kind of relation to the speed of the loop versus file access times or something since stepping through slowly allows it to execute fine, but I honestly have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: Maybe a bug with Python 3 :) ?

Comment: It might be a bug. A more unlikely assumption is that, if the program doesn't do anything, Windows thinks it isn't responding. But, if you do print something, MS knows the application's working. That happened to me once in VB.NET.

Comment: What are the files it's accessing?  Do they exist?  What do those calls into `story` do?  Can you give a complete, runnable, reproducible example?

Comment: @BrenBarn : They're simple binary files; they do exist, and the calls into `story` merely return a string path.

Comment: How big is `range(story.recentFiles.GetCount())`?

Comment: @BrenBarn : However many recently accessed files there are (I've changed it around). Normally something small, 2 or 3--it's not an index issue of any sort that I can tell. I've stepped through it and double checked, too--it's a mystery to me!

Comment: @WaySpurr-Chen: Do you have any error message printed in a terminal? I think I have seen programs hang on Windows because of this…

Comment: @EOL: Nope, that's the worst part; nothing goes to terminal at all, and if I step through the program then it executes without a problem.

Comment: @WaySpurr-Chen: If I remember correctly, I have seen a similar phenomenon with a C program on Windows. The fact that `print` and stepping through the program change the behavior of the program makes me wonder if this is not related to the terminal in some way. You may want to try to execute your code with a different terminal program.

Comment: Can you put all the paths of the recent file into a list and do the for over that list? It would be interesting to know if it crashes in the loop or when retrieving the recent file paths.

Comment: Change your `os.path.exists` to `os.stat()` (that's what `exists` is doing anyway). See if you still crash.

Comment: Which function is throwing IOError and why?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say much with more details, but here is a theory: when you add `print`, this actually raises an IOError (this is possible, as [documented](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IOError)), which is caught, and `os.path.exists(story.recentFiles.GetHistoryFile(index))` is *not* executed, so your program does not hang.

You can test this with a test like the following (before the code you quote):

```
try:
    print('test')
except IOError:
    with open('ioerror_raised.txt', 'w'):
        pass
```

which will create a file `ioerror_raised.txt` if the `print` raised `IOError`.

This could explain why adding a `print` makes the code run.

(If this is the case, then `os.path.exists(story.recentFiles.GetHistoryFile(index))` should obviously be debugged.)

Answer (score 1):

You create a static list of valid indexes (with range()) at the beginning of the loop, but you are removing files from the list (RemoveRecentFile) within the loop.

So your problem might be, that you start the loop with 10 files, removed one file (eg index 4) because you can't access it, and then try to access file the 10th file (index 9) which is not there anymore because you have moved 5->4, 6->5, 7->6, 8->7, 9->8

Comment: agree, I think it's similar to bubbling in compiler optimization, in which compiler add passes to enable pipe-lining such that information can be piped correct to different stages of different tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You are interfacing with some poorly written C/C#/C++ code so it is hard to pin-point where the error is.

That it is poorly written is apparent from the way the API makes you retrieve list items with a call, rather than just using an index.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're porting your code by hand, but you could always try the automated tool:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html